# hidden-xs-down is not working React bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am trying to hide few columns on mobile screens but its not working for some reason. Here's my code:

```
 <Row>
            <Col className="col-md-2">Route Image</Col>
            <Col className="col-md-3">
                <Row>
                    <Col>Route Name</Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col>Route Location</Col>
                </Row>
            </Col>
            <Col className="col-md-3 hidden-xs-down">Route Difficulty</Col>
            <Col className="col-md-2 hidden-xs-down">Route Length</Col>
            <Col className="col-md-2 hidden-xs-down">View Details</Col>
        </Row>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since Bootstrap v4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#responsive-utilities), all `.hidden-` classes have been removed. You should use `d-none .d-sm-block` instead if you want to hide your element only on xs